# How to estimate the invariant density of iterated function system?

Tags: dynamical-systems

What is an accurate method of estimating the invariant measure (density) of an iterated function system (in 2D) that's based on random iteration?

My goal is to obtain a numerical approximation of the density, and I do this by forming a 2D histogram from a very long random orbit.  The problem, however, is that in certain cases the orbit gets stuck in certain regions, and the entire space is not explored.